# JS signature pad from https://github.com/thread-pond/signature-pad is unable to work on larger touch screens laptops and desktops

Tags: javascript, canvas, signature, pad

I am using the 'jquery.signaturepad.js' library as it appears in the link https://github.com/thread-pond/signature-pad . This library has a signature pad (canvas) for mouse/touch screen signature purpose.  The touch screen signature works when when the device is an Ipad/Iphone and other smaller devices but not on desktop/laptop touch screens.

Is there any fix I could make this library to work both using the mouse and the touch screen (if device is touch screen) in all (most) devices?

I have tried it in all browsers and no luck

Answer (score 0):

I finally found why the event OnTouchStart returns undefined for newer/bigger screen laptops.

I have changed my code from  **`canvas.ontouchstart = function(e) {}`** // which returns undefined to

**`canvas.eddEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {}`**